# Onchange method:Drop down inside List in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a list and some of the indices contain drop down as the item but when I select an item from the drop-down at a particular index of the list but the same selected value get to stick to another index.
for example, I have a list where some of the indices contain the country drop down
such as billing country and shipping country. I just want to differentiate shipping and billing country.

How can I Implement `onChange` in such a way that will provide me different country at a different index?

This is my list item

```
 Container item(double width,Fieldlist field,int index){
   return Container(
           child: field.fieldname.toLowerCase().contains('country')||field.fieldname.toLowerCase().contains('state')?
           countryContainer(width,field,index): textFieldContainer(width,field),
   );
  }
```

this is my country drop down container block

```
Container countryContainer(double width,Fieldlist field,int index){
  return  Container(
      child:DropdownButtonHideUnderline (
    child: DropdownButton(
      value: _country,
      items: _dropDownCountry,
      onChanged:(Country val){
        enteredValueMap[field.reqKeyValue]=val.countrycode;
        setState(() {
          _country = val;
          _country=cs.getCountry().indexOf(val) as Country;
        });
      },),));}
```

I have tried to find drop down index but unable to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the value of the drop down button as a list and use the index passed to the function for the list and in the set state function, set the value of the list of that index = to val.
Funtion :

```
Container countryContainer(double width,Fieldlist field,int index){
  return  Container(
      child:DropdownButtonHideUnderline (
    child: DropdownButton(
      value: _country[index],  //added [index]
      items: _dropDownCountry,
      onChanged:(Country val){
        enteredValueMap[field.reqKeyValue]=val.countrycode;
        setState(() {
          _country[index] = val; //added [index]
        });
      },),));}
```

Don't forget to initialize the list with values found in items (_dropDownCountry) or leave them null.